# Lost window borders in Firefox while loading a local html file

Tags: 12.04, compiz, firefox, gnome-classic

[image]

Firefox 16, Ubuntu 12.04, Gnome Classic Session, Compiz effects enabled.
Is this a bug? Anybody else having this? What shall I do?

Comment: Does this really only happen with local HTML files? You screenshot suggests that you open a normal webpage.

Comment: I think, your unity crashed. Look at this question [how do I reset unity config?](http://askubuntu.com/q/17610/61218)

Comment: @qbi : Yes! I switched the tabs. I just loaded an **empty** html file. A.S. - I'm not using Unity... I'm on Gnome Classic Session. :(

Comment: @Naveen my bad. I mean your compiz is crashed.

Answer (score 2):

- Open a terminal and install `compizconfig-settings-manager`

  ```
   sudo apt-get install  compizconfig-settings-manager
  ```
- Then open it by going to *Menu* → *System tools* → *Preferences* in Gnome-classic.
- Click on the **Preference** button on the left side (bottom)
- In the *Profile* section, there is a button named **Reset to defaults**. Click on that button. Wait.... and then Logout from the session
- Login again to see the result

---

**Note**: If the resetting get frozen, Try to Logout from the session forcefully, by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Del</kbd> keyboard shortcut.

Comment: Thanks, but do i need to give up on my effects to do this? I forgot to say, i'm using patched compiz called 'compiz preprosed' or some thing from a ppa. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Naveen I think, yes. The settings will be reset to defaults. but you can then re-customize the settings